# Decrypt "key" that is encrypted with LMK or TMK

Tags: encryption, hsm

New to HSM (Thales payshield 9000), I'm working on DUKPT algorithm. I manage to derive the IPEK(encrypted either under LMK or TMK), but I need to inject a plain text IPEK into an end point device. I don't think my end point device can support encrypted IPEK injection. Any expert here can share with me any idea, on how I getting the IPEK in plain text?

Basically my aim is to decrypt any "key" that is encrypted with LMK or TMK.

Comment: Use decrypt(key) and LMK for TMK

Comment: currently the HSM is in version 2.0c, do you mind to tell me which command code for that?